# Build and use a docker image without involving docker.io

Tags: docker

I'm using `docker build -t myimage:latest .` and then have a separate Dockerfile using that base image:

```
FROM myimage:latest
...
```

But when I try to `docker build .` for that second Dockerfile, I'm getting an error as its trying to pull from docker.io

```
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/myimage:latest:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Is there a way to build and tag images intended only for local use? I can see `myImage` when I search for it locally: `docker image ls | grep myimage`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the same image name everywhere?  What's the `docker build` command to build the first image, and the output of `docker images`?  Image names without an explicit registry default to `docker.io/library/...` and that's normal and not a bug; there's no way to change or disable that.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the `latest` tag.

You could try another tag:

```sh
echo 'FROM busybox' > Dockerfile
docker build -t myimage:dev .

echo 'FROM myimage:dev' > Dockerfile
docker build .
```